# Save the reordered core data object back iOS iOS swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have implemented database with core data that has 7 records. I have implement the collection view to display the data in 3X3 format. I have also implemented the re-arrange of collection cell, during which I will update the NSManagedObject. I want to save back the rearranged object back to my database so that what ever the user rearrange remain persistent to the device. Please find my below code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let managedContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Sample")
    do {

        people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let managedContext = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let temp = people.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
    people.insert(temp, at: destinationIndexPath.item)

    do {

        try managedContext.save()

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }


}
```

Please let me know if I miss any thing

Comment: A Core Data store is unordered; if you want a specific order then you need to sort the data when you query for it; you could add an integer attribute and sort based on that (changing the value as required when your items are re-ordered)

Comment: @Paulw11: I can add one more attribute , but it will be difficult to update data of that when I rearrange  the cells. You have any idea on that?

Comment: It's not that hard.  After the cells are reorganised, simply iterate over your array of Core Data objects, setting the "index" property to their position in the array and then save the objects.